How to Handle reCAPTCHA v2 Checkbox After Safetynet API Deprecation?
I'm currently using Google reCAPTCHA v2 Checkbox for user verification in my Flutter app, implemented via the grecaptcha package. Recently, I learned that Google is deprecating the SafetyNet API, so I removed it from my build.gradle file.

After this change, I'm encountering a SafetyNet API Deprecation error. To address this, I attempted to implement reCAPTCHA using a WebView in my Flutter app, but I'm now facing an "Invalid Domain for Site Key" error.

Despite these efforts, I'm still encountering the following issues:
"Invalid Domain for Site Key" error when using WebView.
Has anyone else faced these issues? How can I resolve the SafetyNet deprecation while properly integrating reCAPTCHA? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
Here are the steps I’ve taken so far:

Removed SafetyNet API from build.gradle.
Attempted to implement reCAPTCHA v2 in a WebView.
Ensured that my site key is correctly configured in the Google reCAPTCHA admin console.

